# python Decimal - checking if integer

Tags: python, format, decimal

I am using the Decimal library in Python, and printing out the values using 
`format(value, 'f')`, where value is a `Decimal`. I get numbers in the form `10.00000`, which reflects the precision on the decimal. I know that `float`  supports `is_integer`, but there seems to be a lack of a similar API for decimals. I was wondering if there was a way around this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use the modulo operation to check if there is a non-integer remainder:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('3.14') % 1 == 0
False
>>> Decimal('3') % 1 == 0
True
>>> Decimal('3.0') % 1 == 0
True
```

Comment: this method does not work if a value is too big, it gives you `decimal.InvalidOperation: quotient too large in //, % or divmod`

Comment: how large is too large? somewhere over 10^20
ref: [DivisionImpossible for very large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868278/decimal-invalidoperation-divisionimpossible-for-very-large-numbers)

Answer (score 13):

As of Python 3.6, `Decimal` has a method [`as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.as_integer_ratio).

`as_integer_ratio()` returns a (numerator, denominator) tuple. If the denominator is 1, then the value is an integer.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("123.456").as_integer_ratio()[1] == 1
False
>>> Decimal("123.000").as_integer_ratio()[1] == 1
True
```

Answer (score 9):

Try `math.floor(val) == val` or `val == int(val)`.

Comment: The `int` suggestion is good.  `math.floor` is a poor choice because it relies on floats, which cannot accurately represent Decimals.  And you even have to import a module just to get this inaccurate result.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it the math version isn't the best idea. I'd just finished writing some math-intensive JavaScript when I wrote the answer, so the js Math object was still stuck in my brain.

Comment: Using int(val) successfully.

Comment: `val == int(val)` seems to work well for large numbers, while the modulo-based solution fails.

Answer (score 6):

The mathematical solution is to convert your decimal number to integer and then test its equality with your number.

Since `Decimal` can have an arbitrary precision, you should not convert it to `int` or `float`.

Fortunately, the `Decimal`class has a [`to_integral_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.to_integral_value) which make the conversion for you. You can adopt a solution like this:

```
def is_integer(d):
    return d == d.to_integral_value()
```

Example:

```
from decimal import Decimal

d_int = Decimal(3)
assert is_integer(d_int)

d_float = Decimal(3.1415)
assert not is_integer(d_float)
```

Comment: Converting `Decimal` value to integer is right... but why can't you use `int`?  Python transparently uses arbitrary-precision integers as necessary.

Comment: Yes, you can convert to arbritrary-precision integer, but I'm not sure it is more efficient than using `to_integral_value()`.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about efficiency. You said `int` wouldn't be able to handle it. Until it's shown that `int` is too slow of a solution, there is no reason to bring up something more complicated.

Comment: Incidentally, on my machine, `int` is faster than `to_integral_value`.

Answer (score 3):

Decimal does have a "hidden" method called _isinteger() that works kind of the like the float's is_integer() method:

```
>>> Decimal(1)._isinteger()
True
>>> Decimal(1.1)._isinteger()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\decimal.py", line 649, in __new__
    "First convert the float to a string")
TypeError: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string
```

As you can see, you would have to catch an exception though. Alternatively, you could do the test on the value BEFORE you pass it to Decimal using the float's method as you mentioned or by using isinstance.

Comment: Now the only issue i see , is_integer does not seem to work as i would expect. This might have to do with float representation. 
Conside this:
num1 = 0.00002

Comment: Yeah, I get a traceback about needing to convert the float into a string if I do that. Not sure why that's implemented that way.

Comment: As of Python 2.7, [Decimal instances can be constructed directly from floats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.from_float).

Comment: The leading underscore means it's a private method so I don't think using it outside would be considered pythonic...

Comment: Python 3.6: `AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute '_isinteger'`

Answer (score 1):

You can call `as_tuple()` on a Decimal object to get the **sign**, the sequence of **digits**, and the **exponent** which together define the Decimal value.

If the exponent of a normalized Decimal is non-negative, then your value doesn't have a fractional component, i.e., it is an integer.  So you can check for this very easily:

```python
def is_integer(dec):
    """True if the given Decimal value is an integer, False otherwise."""
    return dec.normalize().as_tuple()[2] >= 0
```

Try it and see:

```python
from decimal import Decimal


decimals = [
    Decimal('0'),
    Decimal('0.0000'),
    Decimal('1'),
    Decimal('-1'),
    Decimal('1000000'),
    Decimal('0.1'),
    Decimal('-0.0000000009'),
    Decimal('32.4')]

for d in decimals:
    print("Is {} an integer? {}".format(d, is_integer(d)))
```

```
Is 0 an integer? True
Is 0.0000 an integer? True
Is 1 an integer? True
Is -1 an integer? True
Is 1000000 an integer? True
Is 0.1 an integer? False
Is -9E-10 an integer? False
Is 32.4 an integer? False
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what was said above, I used:

```
>>> not 2.5 % 1
False
>>> not 1.0 % 1
True
>>> not 14.000001 % 1
False
>>> not 2.00000000 % 1
True
```

So you can use the following one liner:

```
not value % 1
```

It will provide you with your desired bool.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal class has a function `to_integral_exact` which converts decimal to an integer and also signals if there were any non-zero digits discarded.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.to_integral_exact

Using this information we can implment float's `is_integer` for Decimal too:

```
import decimal
def is_integer(value: decimal.Decimal) -> bool:
   is_it = True
   context = decimal.getcontext()
   context.clear_flags()
   exact = value.to_integral_exact()
   if context.flags[decimal.Inexact]:
     is_it = False
   context.clear_flags()
   return is_it
```

Using the function above:

```
# tested on Python 3.9
>>> is_integer(decimal.Decimal("0.23"))
False
>>> is_integer(decimal.Decimal("5.0000"))
True
>>> is_integer(decimal.Decimal("5.0001"))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it is to use the [`quantize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method which is generally used to round decimals:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> for d in (Decimal('2.72'), Decimal('3.14'), Decimal('3.0'), Decimal('3')):
...     d == d.quantize(Decimal('1'))
... 
False
False
True
True
```