# decimal.InvalidOperation, DivisionImpossible for very large numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3.5.2

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('12') % Decimal('0.01')
Decimal('0.00')
>>> Decimal('234567') % Decimal('0.01')
Decimal('0.00')
```

Works as expected. But...

```
>>> Decimal('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450') % Decimal('0.01')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
```

EDIT: This is the smallest number I found that can cause this error:

```
>>> Decimal(10**26) % Decimal('0.01') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
```

Why does `Decimal(very_large_int) % Decimal('0.01')` give this error? I thought that Decimal is able to handle very large numbers?

Comment: I just posted this because it's curious. Why would Decimal fail in this way? Why is 'DivisionImpossible' when it is clearly possible? (at least for me)

Comment: Why do you use such a huge number that we have to scroll? Does 731671765313306249192251196 not cause the same problem for you? Or did you not try at all to find out the minimum length causing the problem?

Comment: `Decimal` is based on the Decimal Arithmetic specification. You can see [here](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daexcep.html#refexcep) that "Division impossible" means that "the integer result of a divide-integer or remainder operation had too many digits (would be longer than precision)."

Comment: `1*10**x` dies at `27` `InvalidOperation: quotient too large in //, % or divmod`

Answer (score 6):

As [L3viathan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42868424/1256452), the problem is that a result (not **the** result—this is the "hidden part" I mention in a comment) has overrun the available precision.

The hidden part is more obvious if we use Python2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/d.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(big % Decimal('0.01'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1460, in __mod__
    remainder = self._divide(other, context)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1381, in _divide
    'quotient too large in //, % or divmod')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3873, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
InvalidOperation: quotient too large in //, % or divmod
```

Essentially, `a % b` is implemented by doing both division and modulus together (a la Algorithm D in Knuth vol 2; for a C implementation restricted to two fullwords, see the [qdivrem.c code I wrote in the early 2000s](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/433bd38e3a0349f9f89f9d54594172c75b002b74/stand/libsa/qdivrem.c)).  The library code therefore needs two extra digits (the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in `Decimal('0.01')`—calculating the actual number of digits needed is not as simple as for `big` below as we have to look at the exponents) to compute the intermediate quotient.

The decimal library was reimplemented directly in C for Python3, which hides the detail, but the cure is the same for both: extend the precision.  Here's an example source routine that catches the exception and tries again, though with magic constant 2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import decimal
Decimal = decimal.Decimal
import traceback
big = Decimal(
    '731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277'
    '4506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379'
    '5833195285320880551112540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043'
    '5576689664895044524452316173185640309871112172238311362229893423380'
    '3081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071'
    '3810515859307960866701724271218839987979087922749219016997208880937'
    '7665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525849077116705'
    '5601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862'
    '5693219784686224828397224137565705605749026140797296865241453510047'
    '4821663704844031998900088952434506585412275886668811642717147992444'
    '2928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489'
    '1288314260769004224219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408'
    '0719840385096245544436298123098787992724428490918884580156166097919'
    '1338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315'
    '520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')
try:
    print(big % Decimal('0.01'))
except decimal.DecimalException:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print('')
    ctx = decimal.getcontext()
    print('failed because precision was', ctx.prec, 'and big is',
        len(big.as_tuple().digits), 'digits long')
    print('trying again with 2 more digits')
    with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec = len(big.as_tuple().digits) + 2
        try:
            print(big % Decimal('0.01'))
        except decimal.DecimalException:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

With Python2:

```
$ python2 /tmp/d.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/d.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(big % Decimal('0.01'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1460, in __mod__
    remainder = self._divide(other, context)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 1381, in _divide
    'quotient too large in //, % or divmod')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 3873, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
InvalidOperation: quotient too large in //, % or divmod

failed because precision was 28 and big is 1000 digits long
trying again with 2 more digits
0.00
```

With Python3:

```
$ python3 /tmp/d.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/d.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(big % Decimal('0.01'))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]

failed because precision was 28 and big is 1000 digits long
trying again with 2 more digits
0.00
```

Note that dividing by a very large number is actually easier: it's the division by `0.01` that is causing problems here.  If the exponent on the divisor were at least 1000 - 28 (1e972 or larger), we would not have the problem.

Answer (score 4):

`Decimal` is based on the Decimal Arithmetic specification. You can see [here](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daexcep.html#refexcep) that "Division impossible" means that

> the integer result of a divide-integer or remainder operation had too many digits (would be longer than precision).

This precision is something you can adjust:

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec=10000
>>> Decimal('7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088
... 0551112540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557668966489504452445231617318564030987111217223831136222989342338030813533627661428280644448664523874
... 9303589072962904915604407723907138105158593079608667017242712188399879790879227492190169972088809377665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243525
... 8490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637
... 0484403199890008895243450658541227588666881164271714799244429282308634656748139191231628245861786645835912456652947654568284891288314260769004224219022671
... 0556263211111093705442175069416589604080719840385096245544436298123098787992724428490918884580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606058861164671094
... 0507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450') % Decimal('0.01')
Decimal('0.00')
```

Comment: But the result **doesn't** have too many digits. The result is 0. The same as when using smaller numbers.

Comment: @StefanPochmann True, I think the implementation isn't true to those words in this case. I assume it just means "I can't handle an integer division/remainder operation with numbers bigger than $precision".

Comment: That can't quite be it, either, as that huge number with `% Decimal(str(10**990))` does work (results in `Decimal('1.330624919225119674426574742E+989')`).

Comment: It *is* the reason, but there's a hidden part.

Comment: @torek What hidden part?