# Rounding errors for very large numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, rounding

Rounding obscenely large numbers with a lot of decimals gives an error. What's the limit on this type of decimal rounding? I'm very much a beginner with Python so I'm not sure if there's another way around this.

```
from decimal import *
print(round(Decimal((0.123456789123456789123456789123456789123)+12345678912345678912345678), 2))
```

Output:

> 12345678912345678704279552.00

Notice the extra digit on the int:

```
from decimal import *
print(round(Decimal((0.123456789123456789123456789123456789123)+123456789123456789123456789), 2))
```

Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to common misconception, the `decimal` module does not perform exact arithmetic. It performs adjustable-precision, decimal, floating-point arithmetic.

The `decimal` module defaults to 28-decimal-digit precision. The rounding operation you requested needs at least 29-digit precision, and rather than silently giving you less precision, `decimal` throws an error for this particular operation.

Of course, the operations you *wanted* to perform involve much higher than 29-digit precision, but because you did half your math in `float` arithmetic instead of `decimal` arithmetic, you lost most of your precision before `decimal` could even get involved. `float` has a little less than 16 decimal digits of precision. Wrapping a `float` computation in a `Decimal` call won't do the math in `Decimal` arithmetic; you need to *start* with `Decimal`:

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100 # enough
print(round(decimal.Decimal('0.123456789123456789123456789123456789123')+
            decimal.Decimal('123456789123456789123456789'), 2))
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. I actually found another thread that addresses something similar. Will leave it here for future seekers. It gives some additional information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868278/decimal-invalidoperation-divisionimpossible-for-very-large-numbers