# Distinguish whole numbers and decimals

Tags: python, math

I want to know if there is any way to differentiate a whole number from any other output only using maths, eg if you have the number 5 I would like to convert that into the number 0 using equations, however, the number 5.4342 would output the number -1

(What i am trying to do is very hard to put into words so i can clear up any questions)

Comment: `(type(x) == int) - 1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python Decimal - checking if integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965018/python-decimal-checking-if-integer)

Comment: @balandongiv That question is mostly specific to the `Decimal` library, not ordinary `float` values.

Comment: @Julien `type(x)` is not a mathematical operation.

Comment: Why do you have to do it using only maths?

Comment: Define "maths".

Comment: *"i can clear up any questions"* - And are you ever going to do that? Or did you just dump that question here and instantly walk away?

Comment: @Barmar Define 'mathematical', ultimately it's all all comparisons of binary numbers, seems pretty mathematical to me... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `type()` to check if it's an integer or a float. In python, it's usually best to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, if you allow integer divisions, you could use this:

```
def isInt(n): return 0**(n-n//1)-1

isInt(5) # 0

isInt(5.4342) # -1.0
```

If can also work with a modulo:

```
def isInt(n): return 0**(n%1)-1
```